# Isolating an html element with python

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Hi I'm using beautiful soup to parse html on python3.4, and I cant seem to find the right code to properly display the information inside these html tags. I've successfully parsed and extracted info from other sites but for some reason when I finish the loop to display content with this code, empty brackets appear [] as if there were no info.

```
web=requests.get('https://www.scutify.com/company.aspx?ticker=AAPL')
    Info=web.content
    Scutify=BeautifulSoup(Info,'html.parser')
    price=Scutify.find_all('span',{"id":"latest-price"})
    print(price)
    for item in price:
        print(item.content)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because there isn't any content. The prices are dynamically generated by javascript on the page. Requests and BeautifulSoup can't get that data because they don't execute javascript, they just read the code as strings.

That said, you're in luck. Reading the javascript reveals a predictable URL you can use to get all the ticker information in JSON: /service/get-quote.ashx?ticker=

So to get AAPL's info all you do is GET https://www.scutify.com/service/get-quote.ashx?ticker=AAPL

Comment: If I may ask, how did you find that URL?